# Is it possible to prove $a^{5n}b^{3m}c^{n}d^{m}$ is irregular knowing $a^nb^n$ is irregular?

Tags: formal-languages

The proof using the pumping lemma is super easy but is it possible to solve it without pumping lemma and knowing $a^nb^n$ is irregular ?

Comment: What do you mean by "prove $a^{5n}b^{3m}c^{n}d^{m}$"? Do you mean to prove that the associated language is irregular?

Comment: Yes I forgot to mention

Comment: Great, thanks for clarifying. You might also be aware from your previous questions that askers on this site are expected to provide some context for their questions, as is [clarified here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). It would therefore be helpful if you could say a few words about any thoughts you have on the question or what you've tried so far.

Comment: Yes I'm aware. The point is I've got no clues the only context I myself have is that I can solve it via pumping lemma but the question I'm asked is to prove irregularity using irregularity of $a^nb^n$ which is something neither my teacher nor anywhere in the internet haven't said anything about it. And that's why I've asked "Is it possible" which means is any context available actually for that ? ...

Comment: Do you know that regular languages are closed under string homomorphism and inverse homomorphism?

Comment: @ParsaNoori If you can use string homomorphisms, then you could conclude that if this language *were* regular, then $a^{5n}c^n$ must also be regular, but this is irregular for the same reason that $a^n b^n$ is irregular

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we can use homomorphism to solve problem.
Define h(L) :
h(a) = a
h(b) = a
h(c) = bbbbb
h(d) = bbb

h(L) = a^(5n)a^(3m) (bbbbb)^n(bbb)^m =
a^(5n)a^(3m) b^(5n)b^(3m) = a^(5n+3m) b^(5n+3m)

Define C = 5n+3m  ---->  h(L) = a^C b^C
Then we can show that a^C b^C is irregular with pumping lemma. Or show a^C b^C is irregular with pigeonhole principle easily.
If h(L) is irregular, L is irregular too.
So we solve the problem :)

Comment: h(a) = a, h(b) = a, h(c) = bbbbb, h(d) = bbb; we should separate them in solution